# arXiv Submission Error with \dotfill

Tags: tables, nicematrix, arxiv

I have an Overleaf file which includes tables I've inserted dotted lines into using \dotfill. I have changed the Tex Live compiler to the 2020 version, and am exporting the zipped source using the Overleaf "submit" button.

The minimal working example at the bottom of this question compiles correctly for me in Overleaf, but fails when I submit it to arXiv, with the following error:

> ! Undefined control sequence.
> \@sharp ->\dotfill
>
> l.13 \multicolumn{3}{c}{\dotfill}
> \\
> ?
> ! Emergency stop.
> \@sharp ->\dotfill

Any idea how to fix this? Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2.5pt}
    % \footnotesize
    \begin{NiceTabular}{lcc}
       \toprule
       Some & Content & Here\\[-4pt]
       \multicolumn{3}{c}{\dotfill}\\
       More & Content & Here \\
       \bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabular}
    \caption{A table with dotted lines
    }
    \label{tab:multi}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it errors in texlive 2023 too, and it is a bug in nicematrix. It uses `\__nicematrix_old_dotfill:` and `\__nicematrix_old_dotfill` (the second miss the colon).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer -- thank you!! Using NiceTabular instead of just tabular was a hold-over from a prior version, and no longer necessary; I replaced it with tabular and was able to submit my paper to arXiv including the dotted lines :D

Comment: but you should report that to the nicetabular author.

Answer (score 3):

This bug has been corrected in the latest version of `nicematrix` (v 6.18 of 2023-04-19).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2.5pt}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{lcc}
       \toprule
       Some & Content & Here\\[-4pt]
       \multicolumn{3}{c}{\dotfill}\\
       More & Content & Here \\
       \bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabular}
    \caption{A table with dotted lines
    }
    \label{tab:multi}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Of course, with this example, there is no point using `{NiceTabular}`. The classical `{tabular}` will do the job. It's only an example.